# Is $ \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^x} = 1 $ an abuse of notation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, notation

Is $ \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^x} = 1 $ correct or is it just a shortened way to say $ \lim_{y \to \infty } \sum_{x=1}^{y+1} \frac{1}{2^x} = 1 $ ?

In a softer way of asking this question if we could add up all the numbers of the sequence would it equal 1 or are we treating the limit of the partial sums as the sum as a matter of convenience?

It was a something I was wondering about when I was recalling the classic joke "$\aleph_0$ mathematicians walk into the bar the first orders half a glass of beer..." and thinking a little philosophically about if the sum was "really" the sum of the cups or something else.

Comment: It is indeed a shortened way to talk about the limit of the sequence of partial sums.  That doesn't make the first any less correct however.

Comment: it is perhaps abuse of conventions ... $x$ and $y$ usually stand for reals, so it would be more natural to write $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} = 1$ and $\lim_{k \to \infty } \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{2^n} = 1$.

Comment: In my opinion, abuse of notation occurs when clarity is sacrificed for conciseness, when symbols are preferred over words. e.g., "Bernie Sanders can win the nomination $\iff \forall$ superdelegates..."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Recall that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k$ is, [*by definition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)#Definition), $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n$, where, for every $n\geqslant1$, $s_n=x_1+\cdots+x_n$. There is no abuse of notation. There may be, perhaps, a *misinterpretation* of notation, taking the notation to mean more than it describes, but that is on the reader's behalf.

Comment: Perfect use of the word "misinterpretation". +1

Comment: In fact it's not an abuse of notation, it *is* a notation!